# DB2 extract with vbscript

Tags: vbscript, character-encoding, db2

i want to extract data from db2 mainframe which uses IBM code page 285 (EBCDIC code page)
 with vbscript but saving this file (xml data) it displays wrong way.
 How can i convert vbscript RecSet from 285 to ASCII or UTF-8 before saving file?

```
Function used for saving file:
Function WriteFileText( sText, sFileName)
    Dim sFilePath
Dim objFSO 'As FileSystemObject
Dim objTextFile 'As Object
    Dim i
    Dim arr

sFilePath = "c:\jdk1.3\temp\" & sFileName
Const ForWriting = 2


Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(sFilePath, True, True)

a = 0

for i=1 to len(sText)
s2Text = right(left(sText,i),1)
if i > 54 and asc(s2Text) = 63 then a = a + 1 else objTextFile.Write (s2Text) end if
next

objTextFile.Close
```

''    Set objTextFile = objFSO.CreateTextFile(sFilePath, True, True)
''    used to convert to UTF8, as if only one True error appears when writing to file

Comment: Function used to save RecSet:

Answer (score 0):

See [How to convert between ASCII and EBCDIC character codes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/216399). It's written in VB but whould be easy to convert to VBScript.